# python, logging to db Azure by ActiveDirectoryPassword

Tags: python, azure

I connecting to database on Azure using authentication ActiveDirectoryPassword.
ss
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+host+';UID='+user+';PWD='+password+';Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword')

It is working. The issue is that using this connection string I do not specify the DB. It just connecting me to master. How can I switch to DB I need. I have tried different connection strings (with database specified) but only this one works with ActiveDirectiryPassword.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below :

```
pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+host+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+user+';PWD='+password+';Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword')
```

Comment: Please consider accepting this solution if it had helped :)
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work